# Combine two connected sheets into one graph

Tags: google-sheets

I crated two databases from custom queries (using data connectors -> connect to Bigquery).
I want to create one graph which contains data from both.

Can I do that in google sheets? I the chart editor I can't see any option to add another database:
[image]

Comment: most likely not in chart editor. both your dataset needs to be queried in a "range" which you can feed to chart editor

Comment: can you share more information on your setup? If possible sharing the sheet would be great to try it